# R ShinyApps: Dynamic module import causes app to render wrong tab

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am having a shiny app that is heavily relying on modules. Basically it's a big navbarPage with different menus and tabs where every tab is wrapped as a module. Below I provided a minimal example with 2 tabs, but in reality there are more than 20.

```
# module 1 ------------------------------------------------
moduleOneUI <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  tagList(
    h2("module1"),
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}

moduleOne <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({"one yo"})
}

# module 2 ------------------------------------------------
moduleTwoUI <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  tagList(
    h2("module2"),
    textOutput(ns("text"))
  )
}

moduleTwo <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({"two yo"})
}

# main app ------------------------------------------------
ui <- navbarPage(
  "dashboard",
  navbarMenu(
    "#1",
    tabPanel(
      "mod1",
      uiOutput("module_one")
    )
  ),

  navbarMenu(
    "#2",
    tabPanel(
      "mod2",
      uiOutput("module_two")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$module_one <- renderUI({
    moduleOneUI("module_one")
  })
  callModule(moduleOne, "module_one")

  output$module_two <- renderUI({
    moduleTwoUI("module_two")
  })
  callModule(moduleTwo, "module_two")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you might see the server function gets very large with this hard coded server function. So I tried to create it in a more dynamic way using a loop:

```
modules <- list(
  module_one = c(ui = moduleOneUI, server = moduleOne),
  module_two = c(ui = moduleTwoUI, server = moduleTwo)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  for (mod_id in names(modules)) {
    module <- modules[[mod_id]]
    ui_func <- module$ui
    server_func <- module$server

    output[[mod_name]] <- renderUI({
      ui_func(mod_id)
    })
    callModule(server_func, mod_id)
  }
}
```

However, this approach fails to work as expected. Now I see the moduleTwo code rendered in my module_one tab:
[image]

Does any1 know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I really need a dynamic approach to render all those modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two `renderUI` expressions aren't evaluated until after the loop completes and `mod_id = "module_two"`.

To get around this, you can create a [`local`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) scope for each loop iteration:

```
for (mod_id in names(modules)) {
  local({
    mod_id <- mod_id

    module <- modules[[mod_id]]
    ui_func <- module$ui
    server_func <- module$server

    output[[mod_id]] <- renderUI({
      ui_func(mod_id)
    })

    callModule(server_func, mod_id)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution for that problem. If I define a function that calls the module everything works as expected.

```
create_tab <- function(mod_id, output) {
  module <- modules[[mod_id]]
  ui_func <- module$ui
  server_func <- module$server

  output[[mod_id]] <- renderUI({
    ui_func(mod_id)
  })
  callModule(server_func, mod_id)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  lapply(names(modules), create_tab, output = output)
}
```

However, I have no idea why this is working and the other approach isn't. I assume it has something to do with scoping in R.

Comment: This works because `lapply` forces evaluation of arguments passed into the function. All the `apply` functions were changed to do this in R 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for that info! However, it also seems works without the lapply when doing it like this:
`for (mod_id in names(modules)) {
    create_tab(mod_id, output)
}`

Comment: Aha, I realize why that works now. `mod_id` is used outside the `renderUI` expression. So by the time the `renderUI` expressions are evaluated, `mod_id` would have already been evaluated for the corresponding `create_tab` function environment.